# Vertical Gradient

Tags: css

I am unable to get this gradient to go from left to right. Currently it goes from top to bottom.

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(166, 230, 230)), color-stop(0.33, rgb(231, 231, 231)), color-stop(0.15, rgb(255, 255, 255)));
```

I tried cahnge the left top, left bottom to left, right but then nothing shows up. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `-webkit-linear-gradient` form:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgb(166,230,230) 0, rgb(255,255,255) 15%, rgb(231,231,231) 33%);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/45PQd/1

Or, if you really want to use the more verbose format, use `left top, right top`:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgb(166, 230, 230)), color-stop(0.33, rgb(231, 231, 231)), color-stop(0.15, rgb(255, 255, 255)));
```